# Replacing multiple strings with data solely from a CSV file

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, replace

I've got a CSV file with both the data I want to replace in an XML and the data I want to replace it with; Header A is what I want to replace; Header B is what I want to replace it with:

```
HeaderA, HeaderB 
Data A1, Data B1
Data A2, Data B2
Data A3, Data B3
```

I'm trying to do this with power-shell using this solution provided here:

[Replace multiple Strings with Data from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143420/replace-multiple-strings-with-data-from-csv)

Modifying the solution provided there to:

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv .\MyCSV.csv
$xml = Get-Content -Raw .\MyXML.xml
foreach ($row in $CSVData) {
    $xml.Replace($row.HeaderA, $row.HeaderB) |
      Out-File ".\MyXMLCopy.xml"
}
```

I only need the XML as one file; as opposed to what was needed there.

EDIT: What about combining this operation with a multiple file replace? As discussed: [Replace multiple strings in a file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646293/replace-multiple-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell)
So far I've been attempting this:

```
       $ReplaceList = Import-Csv ".MyCSV.csv"
        $ChangeList = Get-Childitem ".\*Map.xml" | ForEach-Object FullName

        foreach ($file in $ChangeList) {
        foreach ($row in $ReplaceList) {
            Get-Content $file |
            ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$($row.HeaderA)", "$($row.HeaderB)"} 
| Set-Content $_.FullName
        }}
```

Failing at Set-Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to remember that PowerShell strings are immutable. That means that `$xml.Replace` doesn't change `$xml` in any way, it returns a new string where the replacement has been done. So, in order to keep all replacements you need to set `$xml` to the result of each replacement.

What your code does is take each row, do the replacement on the original xml and write the result to the output file. Thus you only get the result of the last replacement.

The following code assigns `$xml` after each replacement and only outputs the result once.

```bsh
$CSVData = Import-Csv .\MyCSV.csv
$xml = Get-Content -Raw .\MyXML.xml
foreach ($row in $CSVData) {
    $xml = $xml.Replace($row.HeaderA, $row.HeaderB) 
}
$xml | Out-File ".\MyXMLCopy.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly (I'm fairly new to PowerShell.

Comment: @Christopher Prince: You're welcome, I just added some more info to make it more beginner-friendly.